# How to transform IMG(url.jpg) into html img using php?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to transform all the occurrences `IMG(url.jpg)` into `<img src="/img/url.jpg" />`, from a string, using PHP.

For now, this is my code:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('??????',
   function($img)
   {
       return '<img src="/img/'.$img[0].'" />';
   }
, $content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a callback. A simple `preg_replace` will do:

```
$content = preg_replace('/IMG\(([^\)]+)\)/','<img src="/img/$1" />',$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way to convert from `IMG(url.jpg)` into `<img src="/img/url.jpg" />`

```
<?php    

function convertIMG($img)
   {
       $rest = substr($img, 4, -1); 
       return '<img src="$rest" />';
   }

$before = "IMG(url.jpg)";
$after = convertIMG($before);    

?>
```